# How can I package my python application with external python libraries?

Tags: python, wxpython, packaging

I hope my title was clear. I'm using wxpython for making a GUI and I want it to be able to be opened, extracted, and have it work on all operating systems. I was able to include twill by finding a folder called twill inside the twill archive, which worked fine. However, I'm unable to figure out how to correctly package wxpython.

EDIT: I'm not using either. py2exe is only for windows, and bbfreeze doesn't seem to work on mac (so it's not cross platform)

Comment: Are you compiling the utility with something like py2exe or bbfreeze?  If so, those both contain directives to include / exclude packages or dlls.  Otherwise, more information is necessary to answer this question properly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's just no one stop solution so that a single installable executable will work across all operating systems.  The right solution is really to provide a different installer or executable for each OS;  For windows, use `py2exe`, for mac, `py2app` is a good choice, and for linux you should just provide a tarball with a reasonable `setup.py` (that you will need for the first two, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the recommendation of TokenMacGuy. But I preferrably would use a tool which is able to freeze the application for all OS instead of using different ones.
cx_freeze is a good choice regarding these terms.

This is another fine alternative:

> [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is a program that converts (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works with any version of Python since 2.2, it builds smaller executables thanks to transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full compatibility.

Comment: PyInstaller is an alternative indeed. But be-aware, there are numerous reported issues where virus scanners will report a virus on the executable generated with PyInstaller and these issues will not be solved......
See this list: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues?q=is%3Aissue+virus+is%3Aclosed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/ ?