# How to construct a Python package relying on large system libraries

Tags: python, opencv, pip, distutils

What's the appropriate way of constructing a Python package via disutils when that Python package relies on a large system library?

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917456/how-can-i-package-my-python-application-with-external-python-libraries), but it refers to an installable Python app, not a generic package.

I've written a package that relies on OpenCV. I'm only concerned with supporting Linux distros, but most distros either don't provide OpenCV or provide a version that's too old to use. Unfortunately, OpenCV is to large and cumbersome (and depends on several other system libraries) to include in the package and compile during the build step.

My current approach is to simply do nothing special in my setup.py and just import its Python modules in a try/except, showing a detailed error message if the import fails. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you just specify the python cv module as a dependency? There's [ctypes-opencv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ctypes-opencv) and [pyopencv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyopencv)

Comment: @jterrace, I had considered that, but I'm not sure I want to as those might be very out of date. In order to compile the current OpenCV on Ubuntu 11.10, I had to follow a very complex set of steps, and download and install very specific dependencies not in Ubuntu's standard repos. I'm not confident pip could reproduce those steps.

Comment: I'm wondering exactly the same thing with OpenCV. I don't think you can get around the "large and cumbersome" part though unless you isolate only the parts of OpenCV you want and compile with those. Maybe if you had a binary installer, it could be scripted with the setup?

Comment: Hi @Cerin, I have the exact same problem as you. Have you found a proper solution now ?

Comment: @Cerin, if you found a solution, could you share it with us as an answer?

Comment: @kobejohn, Sorry, but I didn't find a good solution. I settled on simply wrapping my imports in a try/except clause and reporting where to download to download the dependency.

Comment: @Cerin Thanks for the update. I may do the same in the short term with the imports.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zc.buildout: http://www.buildout.org/

You should be able to extend the buildout config for your project from this one: https://github.com/cpsaltis/opencv-buildout